# Android Emulator plugin not working in Jenkins

Tags: java, android, testing, android-emulator, jenkins

When I run test on Jenkins with option create emulator I have this problem:

> [android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to run AVD
>   creation command

When I target existing emulator I have this problem:

> FATAL:
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.android\avd\AVD_2.2.ini (The
>   system cannot find the path specified) java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.android\avd\AVD_2.2.ini (The
>   system cannot find the path specified) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source) at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.util.Utils.parseConfigFile(Utils.java:436)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller$2.call(SdkInstaller.java:331)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller$2.call(SdkInstaller.java:328)
>   at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45) at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.getPlatformFromExistingEmulator(SdkInstaller.java:328)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.getPlatformForEmulator(SdkInstaller.java:312)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.SdkInstaller.installDependencies(SdkInstaller.java:174)
>   at
>   hudson.plugins.android_emulator.AndroidEmulator.setUp(AndroidEmulator.java:247)
>   at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:154) at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1488) at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46) at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88) at
>   hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)

I have this file.
When I run manual emulator and tests on jenkins It works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The path shown in the second case suggests that you may be running Jenkins as a system service.

In which case, you could try the workaround listed under "Known Issues" on the [Android Emulator Plugin wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin#AndroidEmulatorPlugin-Knownissues):

> **Running in a Windows service as "Local System"**
>   New AVDs cannot be generated and run if Jenkins is running as a Windows service, using the "Local System" account (see [issue #7355](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7355)).
>
> Workaround: configure the Jenkins service to "run as" a real user

---

If that doesn't solve the problem, can you tell us in which directory AVDs are placed when you create them manually?  You can find out by running `emulator` with the `-verbose` flag. Within the first few lines you should see something like:

> emulator: Android virtual device file at: c:\users\foo\.android\avd\emu_4.0.3.ini

Comment: Thanks, It's work as simple project, but when I try to use configuration matrix I have a problem with "Process leaked file descriptors". When I run only one configuration I have "completed with result NOT_BUILT"                                                        Can you write in steps how can I fix it with this page: http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build ??