# Jenkins Build Not Emulator

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-espresso, android-testing

I want to test my Android app in Jenkins. I have installed in Jenkins Android Plugin and made other settings. But I always get the following problems.

My Setting

[image]
and ERROR :

[image]

Do you have an idea? How can I create and start an emulator in Jenkins?
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This may be your exact issue:
[Android Emulator plugin not workin in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390241/android-emulator-plugin-not-workin-in-jenkins?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You could also run the full avdmanager.bat command from the jenkins host's command line as the jenkins user (likely jenkins). 
Try adding the -v flag for verbose output https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager .

To see if it creates the emulator you should be able to the Windows equivalent of run:

`emulator -list-avds`